# does last async call in async method require await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I can't understand if await statement is required when async method call is the last call in my async method. E.g.

```
public async Task CallAsync(byte[] data)
{
    await Call1Async(data);
    Call2Async(data);
}

public async Task Call1Async(byte[] data)
{
   ...
}

public async Task Call2Async(byte[] data)
{
   ...
}
```

The above would compile but with a warning "consider applying await to this method". But I think it would be waste of resources to apply await for the last call in the method.

At the same time, if I use `return Call2Async(data);` instead of just `Call2Async(data);`, the warning would go away. This indicates `await` is not actually required in such situation.

But this only works for methods which have a return value (i.e. `Task<T>` rather than just `Task`). I need this for methods without return values. Is there any way to do the same for value-returning methods?

I.e. I need to somehow return `Task` object returned by `Call2Async` to the caller of `CallAsync` and I can't use `return` statement in `CallAsync` explicitly as my methods don't have return values. Of course, I can adjust them all to return values (e.g. true) but it would not be an elegant solution.

P.S. If I have the only async call in my method, I just don't add 'async' to the method signature, and it works ('return' statement not required). But if the method contains more than one async call, I need to have 'async' modifier to be able to await for the first call 'await Call1Async(data)'. And adding 'async' modifier makes the compiler require 'return' to return Task object to the caller (and this works only for methods with return values). That's what I'm trying to overcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following method:

```
public async Task CallAsync(byte[] data)
{
    await Call1Async(data);
    Call2Async(data);
}
```

Control from the method returns after beginning `Call2Async`. That is, if you were to `await CallAsync(data)`, it would finish before `Call2Async` ends. This is probably not what you intended. This method will only finish when both calls are complete:

```
public async Task CallAsync(byte[] data)
{
    await Call1Async(data);
    await Call2Async(data);
}
```

You can see the difference in these example outputs (I implemented the two async calls to simply print a start, delay for a second, and then print an end).

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main start");
    CallAsync(null).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Main end");
}
```

The method without the second `await` prints:

```
Main start
Call1Async start
Call1Async end
Call2Async start
Main end
Call2Async end
```

And with the second `await`:

```
Main start
Call1Async start
Call1Async end
Call2Async start
Call2Async end
Main end
```

This implementation also has a problem:

```
public Task CallAsync(byte[] data)
{
    Call1Async(data);
    return Call2Async(data);
}
```

It kicks off both async calls at the same time, but then returns control when `Call2Async` completes, whether `Call1Async` is complete or not. Again, this is probably not what you intended.

Comment: @dcastro unless you make `CallAsync`'s type `Task<Task>`, you can't do that: either 1. you include the `async` keyword and can use `await` but have to otherwise write the method like a `void`, or 2. you don't have `async`, can't use `await`, and then return a `Task`

Comment: @TimS. Thanks for reply. So, you confirm that the only way to return from CallAsync to the caller the same Task which is returned by Call2Async is to make all Tasks parametrized, such as Task<bool> even if I don't need any return value?

Comment: @Alex There's typically no need to include a dummy value, or to return `Call2Async`'s `Task`. I'd recommend that you keep them simply `Task` and use both `await`s. You (most likely) don't want to return `Call2Async`'s `Task`, but let `async` generate a `Task` that waits until both async calls are done.

Comment: @Alex if you returned `Call2Async`'s `Task`, then your call to `CallAsync` can't await `Call1Async`'s `Task`. It can fire it off and forget about it, but not await it. That's why you want it to have its own `Task`.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to avoid the extra overhead of generating one more Task by await but most likely the profit of it isn't just worth spending time and adding complexity to the code.

Comment: @Alex You're already generating a `Task` by using `await` the first time. The second `await` does make the code generated for that a bit more complicated, but not drastically so. So yeah, it doesn't make sense to try to do it another way if that will work for you.

Comment: As a note, if `Call1Async` and `Call2Async` are independent (1 doesn't rely on the results of 2), it probably makes sense to do `await Task.WhenAll(Call1Async(data), Call2Async(data))` so that both get kicked off at the same time, instead of running them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

async keyword indicates that the method is asynchronous and than it will contain the await keyword in it. 
I don't understand why you have multiple asynchronous methods?

Consider the following example :

```
async void MyMethod()
{
Task<object> result = MyWorkAsync();

MyIndependentOtherWork();

object res = await result;
}
```

Calling MyWorkAsync is like creating a thread "toto" to execute the method (i.e Thread.Start(MyWorkAsyn))

The await keyword is like making a join form the current thread to the thread "toto" and than getting the result of "toto", and in the mean time you get your other independent work to execute on the current thread

Comment: "Join" is the wrong term here, it does not "join" (join implies one thread waiting for another) it adds a continuation.

Comment: These async methods internally call async sockets. E.g. Call1Async sends a request and Call2Async receives the response.

Comment: That's right Peter, wrong choice of word, the await suspend method execution not the current thread